# java pass data from servelt to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I alreayd saw many questions about this but it the proposed solutions didn't work for me:

In my servlet i do this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setAttribute("title", "Level0and1ForUser");

        request.getRequestDispatcher("./testPages/resultSetFormatter.jsp")
                .forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

And in the jsp page:

```
<title>
<%= request.getParameter("title") %>
</title>
```

the result is null as you see:

[image]

Comment: from my point of view no downvote candidate

Comment: You are writing the value into an *attribute*, then you are trying to read a *parameter*. That's not the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
${requestScope.title}
```

---

## NOTE:

Never use java code inside a jsp page, **its deprecated and highly discouraged**

> The usage of scriptlets is always discouraged. Instead one should use tag libs like JSTL or Expression Language (EL).
>
> The question always arises that why should we not use scriptlets in JSP when the same task can be performed using scriptlets as well.
>
> Here is why one should avoid using scriplets in JSPs:
>
> - JSP Scriptlets reduces the maintainability and readibility of the code and hence making it difficult to read and make further changes.
> - JSP Scriptlets can not be re-used.
> - JSP Scriptlets are not unit-testable.
> - JSP Scriplets merge the presentation with business logic which is highly prone to errors.
> - Last but not least, if JSP Scriptlets throws an exception, it breaks the whole page there and doesn’t move further in the processing.

- [SOURCE](http://thewebplant.com/why-no-scripts-should-be-written-in-jsps-java/)
- [**READ MORE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files?rq=1)

Comment: and what is the possible (better) alternative to my code please ?

Comment: Second line of my answer... Just place it between `<title>` tags

Comment: well the title becomes `{$requestScope.title}` not the actual value of the title, this is the code `<title>
{$requestScope.title}
</title>`

Comment: Wow dude, you just had to copy a single line... Please double check to see typo ;)

Comment: I am sorry, thank you

Comment: My apologizes! Corrected comment and glad to help. Please read the posts about why not use scriptlets, if you are starting with jsp better do it with the right technologies ;)

Comment: please is the same for other variables? for example when I send a `Map<String,String>` object from my servlet to my jSP, how can I retrive it? (so I can make loop over it in my JSP ) ? really thanks

Comment: Yes I am reading them right now ,

Comment: Yes with primitive types (string, int, long...) but for Collections or your own ojects you need to convert them using json

Comment: so I should convert my map to JSON in my servlet and send that JSON to my jsp where I loop over it ?

Comment: Yes, but iterate is more for lists or arrays, you might get map info without iterate with a javascript json library

Answer (score 1):

if you put the value in an `attribute` of the `request`, you have to get it in the same way:

```
<title>
<%= (String)request.getAttribute("title") %>
</title>
```

but much more beautiful is Jordi's answer.